# Little-$O$ and Taylor Polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Why do I need to put $o(x^n)$ at the end of a Taylor polynomial? For instance:
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^4)$$

I'm having troubles to understand the utility of the little-$o$ notation.

Comment: Note that in your example we have a big-O term.

Comment: The error term is $O(x^4)$, but $o(x^3)$. Note that $f(x)=g(x)+O(h(x))$ is an abuse of notation for $f(x)\in g(x)+O(h(x))$, i.e. $f(x)-g(x)\in O(h(x))$, since $O(h(x))$ is really a set of functions. Similarly with $o(h(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

If you just wrote
$$ e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6} $$
then it would be a false equality. The goal of Taylor series is to approximate complicated functions with simple functions, namely polynomials, around a given point. Suppose you're working around $0$, you would have $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n+\varepsilon_n(x)$ for some $n\geqslant 0$ and $\varepsilon_n$ a function that is negligeable around $0$ so that as $n$ is chosen to be large, the approximation gets better. What does it mean for $\varepsilon_n$ to be negligeable ? It should mean that $\varepsilon_n$ is way smaller than the approximation, that is $a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$, around $0$. For Taylor series, it is asked that
$$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\varepsilon_n(x)}{a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n}=0 $$
which is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\varepsilon_n(x)}{x^n}=0$ *i.e* $\varepsilon_n(x)=o(x^n)$.